# Java Recursion - Alternative to passing-by-reference:

Tags: java, recursion, pass-by-value

I'm migrating from C to Java and I'm having difficulties with recursion, specially because in Java you can't pass an argument by reference.

What I'm looking is not a solution/trick to force Java pass an argument by reference, but the recommended way to solve such a problem in Java.

Let's take the recursive node insertion in a binary tree:

```
void nodeInsert(Node n, int a) {
    if (n == null)
        n = new Node(a);
...
}
```

In C, by the end of the execution, the node `n` in the tree would point to the newly created node. In Java, however, `n` will still be `null` (because n is passed by value).

What is the suggested Java approach for such problems?
Some approaches I already tried:

- Using a static object to keep track of the parent (issue complicates when using generics).
- Passing the parent node as part of the function. It works but complicates the code a bit and doesn't look as a good solution.
- Creating an additional member pointing to the parent node but this is not a good solution, as it increases the space required by O(n);

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Uh, have you considered returning a Node: `Node nodeInsert(Node n, int a)`?  Or do you need to return ANYTHING - can't you just create the node and add it to your list or tree inside of `insertNode()`?  Why do you think you need an "output parameter"?

Comment: This approach could work indeed but wouldn't it beat the goal of recursion, which is to solve the base case (in this example, when the node is null)?

Comment: If it works, then it meets the goal.

Comment: But this would work in this very simple case, in which only one pointer need to be returned. Wouldn't work in the implementation of the Balanced Trees for sure. That's the reason I'm asking for the best practices instead of only a solution.

Comment: if Node is a custom object its already a ReferenceType , basically when u pass 'n' for next pass it should not be null,you might wana check the code again ,What i am trying to say is Reference to Node is passed as value in java , its just the address again

Answer (score 3):

In Java instead of using *reference variables*, we use **return** values and assign it to the variable that has to be changed.

```
    Node nodeInsert(Node n, int a) {
        if (n == null){
            n = new Node(a);
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            ....
            return nodeInsert(n,a); //this is how a recursion is done.
            ....
        }

    }
```

If you need more on recursion http://www.toves.org/books/java/ch18-recurex/ will teach you right.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to implement is to maintain the node relationships inside the node itself. Quite a lot of examples can be found in implementations of various JDK datastructures. So the Node is the container for the value and contains references to other nodes, depending on the data structure.

If you need a child->parent relationship between nodes, the Node class would look like

```
class Node<T> {
    T value;
    Node parent;
}
```

In case of insert, you create a new node, set the parent reference to the original one, and return the new Node as a result (this is optional, but not uncommon to do, so the call has a handle of the new child)

```
Node<T> insert(Node<T> parent, T value) {
  Node<T> child = new Node<>();
  child.value = value;
  child.parent = parent;
  return child;
}
```

And yes, this adds a minor overhead of 4 bytes per Node (or 8 bytes, on 64bit JVMs without compressed pointers)

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following solutions:

- Implement a method in class `Node` that adds a child node. This makes use of the OO-possibility to encapsulate data and functionality together in a class.
- Change `nodeInsert` to return the new node and add it to the parent in the caller (also mentioned in comments). The responsibility of `nodeInsert` is to create the node. This is a clear responsibility and the method signature shows what the result of the method is. If the creation is not more than `new Node()` it might not be worth to have a separate method for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a holder object that in turn references your new `Node` object

```
void nodeInsert(AtomicReference<Node> r, int a) {
    if (r.get() == null)
        r.set(new Node(a));
...
}
```

Or you could pass an array with space for one element.

Comment: Interesting approach. I will try it.

Comment: @Nelsao Be aware that AtomicReference is a concurrent data structure which may affect performance.

Comment: Passing an array or list, and the callee modifying element(s) in that container, is the common idiom for "out parameters".
"AtomicReference" (not "AtomicReverence" ;)) is probably a poor choice for this problem.  But the real point is: "if you don't NEED an "out parameter" ... then don't try to kludge one".  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

After months posting this question, I realized yet another solution that is, in fact, already contemplated in java design patterns but not mentioned here: Null Object Pattern. 
The downside is that each null occupies memory (in some cases, like large Red-Black trees, this could become significant).